# What numerical integration method can solve a integral over a function that depends on a differential equation without an analytic solution?

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus, runge-kutta-methods

Suppose we have a differential equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=f_{p_x,p_y}(y,x)$. After solving this differential equation for particular values of $p_x$ and $p_y$, we obtain $y_{p_x,p_y}(x)$. With this $y_{p_x,p_y}(x)$, we obtain another function $g(y)$, which is obviously dependent on $p_x$, $p_y$ and $x$. So we can express the newly obtained function as $G(p_x,p_y,x)$. Now, we want to integrate $G$ over $p_x$ and $p_y$ to obtain $I(x)=\int_{p_x}\int_{p_y}G(p_x,p_y,x)dp_x\,dp_y$.

However, since the original differential equation does not have an analytic solution, we have to evaluate $I(x)$ numerically. To do this, we have used the following steps:

1.Define a function $f1(p_x,p_y,x)$ that returns $y_{p_x,p_y}(x)$ // using the Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg 78 method.

2.Define a function $f2(x)$ that returns $I(x)$ // using the GNU Scientific Library CQUAD method.

I used C++ for fast computation. It's worth noting that when evaluating the integral $\int_{p_x}\int_{p_y}G(p_x,p_y,x)dp_x\,dp_y$, we have to evaluate $G(p_x,p_y,x)$ for each step in $p_x$ and $p_y$. This means that we have to solve the differential equation for each step of the integration, which can be time-consuming depending on the number of steps taken by $I(x)$. We need to use an appropriate numerical integration method to solve this problem with accuracy in less time. However, since $f1$ is not a general analytic function, and its values depend on the numerical solution obtained using Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg 78, it is difficult to know how the libraries work internally. When CQUAD tries to return value for $f2$, its adaptive algorithm tries to adapt the error within a limit, it may never achieve this limit as $f1$ is not analytic, and the integration might continue indefinitely. This is currently happening, and the code has been running for the past four days without producing a value.
Therefore, the question is how to numerically solve this kind of problem and which integration methods to use.

Comment: It is not clear what roles $p_x$ and $p_y$ play in your original differential equation. Are they parameters in the definition of $f$? Or are they initial conditions? And it is unclear how $G$ is related to $y_{p_x,p_y}$. When you have no idea about the steps that need to be taken, there also no way to decide what numerical methods could be used in calculating these unknown steps. Thus I do not see any hope of you getting a useful answer as the question is currently formulated.

Comment: @PaulSinclair $p_x$ and $p_y$ are the parameters of f. For example, you can construct G as you wish. Let's say $G=(y^{5/2})sin(y)$.